# Is there any difference between 速さand 速度?

Tags: word-choice, words, etymology, word-usage, wago-and-kango

From what I understood, both **速さ{はやさ}** and **速度{そくど}** means "speed". Some say that they are synonyms (just like *speed* and *velocity* in English), but I guess there is a nuance between them, isn't it ?

**速さ{はやさ}** comes from the adjective **速い{はやい}**, like other adjectives (**長い{ながい}** : **長さ{ながさ}**, **深い{ふかい}** : **深さ{ふかさ}**...), while **速度{そくど}** is the combination of two kanjis : [**速{そく}**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%80%9F#Kanji) (speed), [**度{ど}**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BA%A6#Japanese)(degree).

Can I guess anything based on the words etymology, or is the nuance between them is more subtle ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say there is no difference, at least in everyday language. Maybe　速さ has a slightly more casual feel to it... at least I see more myself using 速さ than 速度 in a daily conversation.

Now, 速度 is **velocity** and 速さ **speed**. That means that in the field of physics, they *are* indeed different, namely:

- velocity is a vector, including not only a value but a direction
- speed is a scalar quantity (the magnitude of the velocity)

edit: just confirmed on [wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6)

> 日常語としての速度と速さはほとんど区別なく使われている [...]
>   対して、物理学においては、速さ（英語: speed）と速度（velocity）を厳密に区別する

Answer (score 3):

As a single word, Nicolas Couvrat is true. 
But when including combination with 速い/遅い, there is a difference.

速さ includes the meaning of 'fast' (<=> 遅さ), whereas 速度 is neutral.
So we say 速度が遅い, but we don't say 速さが遅い。

Example:

1.「見てよ！　この電車の速さ！」= "Look! How fast this train moves!"

2.「見てよ！　この電車の速度！」= "Look! This train's speed!"

This "速度" of 2. can mean slow (like talking about legacy train in rural area).
If you want to explicitly say slow

「見てよ！　この電車の遅さ！」= "Look! How slow this train moves!"